# Entity Framework 6 code first enum data binding

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, data-binding

I have an entity `Product` which has among its fields a `ProductType` field, with values from this enum:

```
public enum ProductType : int
{
    Undefined = 0,
    Simple = 1,
    Composed = 2
}
```

When I display the form to add or edit a Product, I load the values from the enum in the ComboBox corresponding to the product type like this:

```
typeComboBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ProductType));
```

It loads the values fine, and also saves the value to the Products table correctly.

I want that when the value changes to show / hide a button, based on the selected value. This is not happening, the product entity has always the initial value set, but the correct value is saved to the table.

```
btnEditChoices.Visible = _product.Type == ProductType.Composed;
```

Any ideea why this value is not updated on ComboBox change?

Thanks!

Comment: A few silly questions . Is this ASP.Net ? If yes does your typeComboBox1 sends postback to server ?

Comment: A few silly questions again :) If you set breakpoint in this code(btnEditChoices.Visible = ...) it is fired ? If yes, try to find all references to btnEditChoices.Visible in your code. Maybe you rewrite this property in another place.

Comment: Yes, the breakpoint is fired, but the _product.Type is still the old value. But if I continue and press Save button, the new value is persisted to the database.

Comment: are you sure the code shouldn't be : `btnEditChoices.Visible = (ProductType)typeComboBox1.SelectedValue == ProductType.Composed;`

Comment: I don't see your whole code and don't know what is variable _productType, when and how it is changed, but code under should work `btnEditChoices.Visible = typeComboBox1.SelectdeValue == ProductType.Composed;`

Comment: The _product variable is loaded in FormLoad, based on an Id, and after that is added to a BindingSource like this: `productBindingSource.Add(_product);`.

Comment: I think the problem is not here... When EF serializes the entity to the database just read the property _product.Type. Just to understand what's happening you can insert the property getter and setter (with a backing field) and set a breakpoint on them...